# Outer join multiple tables with flattened results

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have found many examples on outer joins but can't quite get the results I want.

Does anyone know if this is possible with out using foreign keys in EF?

Lets say I have a table named Persons it contains

```
PersonID
Name
```

Now I have a table named `FavFoods` where `PersonID` can exist many times or not at all.

```
PersonID
FoodName
```

And I have a 3rd table named `FavShows` where `PersonID` can also exist many times or not at all.

```
PersonID
ShowName
```

Using either lamda or sql like linq expression how would I return from my dbcontext results like this:

```
PersonID    FavFoods         FavShows
0           List<FavFoods>   List<FavShows>
1           List<FavFoods>   List<FavShows>
2           List<FavFoods>   List<FavShows>
```

Instead of something like this where the person is repeated for every possible combination of results:

```
PersonID    FavFoods         FavShows
0           (0, Broccoli)    (0, Seinfeld) 
0           (0, Broccoli)    (0, Simpsons) 
1           (1, Peas)        (1, HSN)
1           (1, Broccoli)    null
1           (1, Peas)        null
1           (1, Broccoli)    (1, HSN)
2           null             null
```

Comment: Are you using entity framework? What's your object model?

Comment: I am using entity framework in my actual code.  I don't have a object model for this particular example it has been overly simplified to post here.  But I would like to assume that each table is separate with no foreign keys linking them, etc.  And the models would look exactly as described with PersonID, FoodName, etc. with the possible addition of FoodID and ShowID in those tables so they have unique keys.

Comment: Using foreign keys and navigation properties on EF would make this easy. If you don't have those available, I think you could go for a more complex select query and return a new type.

Answer (score 1):

If you have FK's defined between the FavFood and FavShow tables and the Person table, then the Person object will be defined as

```
PersonID int;
Name string;
ICollection<FavFood> FavFoods;
ICollection<FavShow> FavShows;
```

ICollection acts like a List. Then your Linq query will be:

```
var people = from p in context.Persons select p;
```

...and people will contain a list of Person instances, each of which will contain lists of linked FavFoods and FavShows.

So basically, if you design the DB correctly, you get what you want right out of the box.

-- EDIT

Given that you can't change the DB, the best way to do this is to change your class definitions to be the way you want them to be i.e. with the ICollections as above. You'll need to add an association to your model: right click on the model background and choose Add > Association, and add the association between the Person and FavFood tables and repeat for FavShow.

There is no single SQL statement that will run the query you want - there can't be as any SQL query can only return one type of row, not the multiple types you want. EF runs multiple queries, one for the 'parents' (Person) and then others for the children when they're accessed (FavFood and FavShow). Changing the EF model to contain the FK's via adding associations to the model is the way to go.

Comment: Simon thank you for your response.  However I cant modify the DB and currently it doesn't have foreign keys that would allow me to do it the easy way.  I am asking how to get the results I want with the example as shown.  No foreign keys, no links between tables at all.  Thanks

Comment: Added to the answer. To make the answer a bit clearer: don't add the ICollections ti the classes, add the Associations to the model and the ICollections will be added automatically.

Comment: Simon, Thanks again for your response I was hoping to only hit the database once to retrieve all the data I needed.  I wasn't 100%  sure if  EF made a second call or not but suspected it would as you have confirmed for me.  Do you know if it is any more efficient to have EF make the second call as you suggest or just make separate calls to the Food and Show tables myself?  If I make separate calls myself I don't really need the Associations as I will then have the data separated as desired with just 2 separate outer joins.

Comment: If you're using EF I would definitely stick with EF all the way. Maintaining a system with 2 ways of accessing the DB is likely to get messy. EF is actually pretty efficient.